# How can i add flag on every new record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this view has been update every single day
and i want to add a new column called [Flag] to indicate whether if the record is new or existing record,(new is 1,old is 0) for eg:
the order is from top to bottom, started from 01/01/2020

old view:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 |
| 3 | 01/02/2020 |
| 1 | 01/02/2020 |
| 2 | 01/03/2020 |

new view:

| ID | Flag | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 3 | 1 | 01/02/2020 |
| 1 | 0 | 01/02/2020 |
| 2 | 0 | 01/03/2020 |
| 4 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |

I tried to use self-join but the result does not showing correctly,
So, im wandering how should i do this? Much Appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you trying to update the old records to a 0 as well after a new record comes in? What are you basing "new" on? an ID of some sort?

Comment: Im sorry.  i just started using stackoverflow,  i dont see my table after i posted.(i can see it when review it) Can any of you see my table or it just will showing words for creator?

Comment: No worries, a mod edited it. I can see your table now. Do you have your flags backwards above? Why is new marked for the older dates?

Comment: I've edited the question so the table shows up. adding `IIF(CAST([Date] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 1, 0)` to your view definition for the flag column should do what you want, I think, though it's a bit unclear what you want.

Comment: No,  the old record will stick with 1,   new will based on date, as long as the same ID already in my view, the new came ID will be marked as 0

Comment: Hey GRIV, im not sure how to reply to you directly, so i will post it here. Please let me know if you can see this.  Here is just an example, whenever the new records come in, it will find if there are any existing records in this view. If it does, make as 0,  if the new coming in record is new, will make as 1

Comment: So new records can come in with older dates? If I'm understanding this correctly and you're basing the flag on newly inserted, vs. latest date?

Comment: hey TZHZ, sorry for misunderstanding, can we use CASE....WHEN here?  cause there are other condition to determine if the record is new or nor( for eg: ID 1 has a category, if next day, ID 1 is coming again but with different category name, it will still marked as 1(new record)

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to make it more clear, show data before insert (flag included) and what you expect it to be after the insert.

Comment: Hey GRIV. No, the order should be from top to bottom, started from 01/01/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to create a `flag` column that returns the **first** `Date` and then a `CASE` statement to compare it to your current `Date`.

If your current row `Date` value matches the **first** `Date` it finds (by `ID`, `category`, *whatever else you want to group by*), it'll return the `flag` with `1`, otherwise it'll return `0`.

Then, `ALTER` your `view` to include the `flag` logic (be sure to get your `views` current logic, appending the `flag` column to it).

```
ALTER VIEW sample_view -- Change to your view name here
AS  
-- Write your query logic here
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN "Date" = FIRST_VALUE("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY ID, category ORDER BY "Date")
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS flag
FROM sample_table -- Change to your table name here
GO
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7_HL9fTg)*.

**Result:**

| ID | Flag | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 3 | 1 | 01/02/2020 |
| 1 | 0 | 01/02/2020 |
| 2 | 0 | 01/03/2020 |
| 4 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |

Also, as noted previously, your column `Date` is a [Reserved Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8#:%7E:text=DISALLOW-,DATE,-%E2%80%94%20See%20DATETIME). It is advised to change it to something else.

Comment: Tysm GRIV,  that is exactly what i need. One thing i noticed quiet interesting, i was testing it on my own view, first i only included ID in partition by, but it magically shows the correct result( for eg: even the id is same  but when category is different, it shows 1 for the new record)  do you know why?

Comment: No problem. Look into the `OVER` clause, particularly the `PARTITION BY` argument [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#partition-by:~:text=2139154666-,PARTITION%20BY,-Divides%20the%20query) which divides the query result set into partitions. If you remove category, it'll partition it by ID only, I think this is what you want. When you have values in category, especially different values, it'll partition the query up further.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute [flag] with a window function

```
select id, [date], sign(row_number() over(patition by id order by [date] desc) - 1) [flag]
from yourtable
```

Not sure if DESC is required, I follow your sample data rather then comments. You may want to revert it to ASC.

Comment: is there anyway i can add this column inside a view?  i was using CASE WHEN....

Comment: Yes the query is correct within a view too.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the date matches the max(date) per grouping of your choice.

```
create view some_view as

select *, case when date=max(date) over (partition by id, category) then 1 else 0 end as flag
from yourtable;
```

You also might want to use a different column name for `date`, which is a reserved keyword

Comment: tysm phil  i used FIRST_VALUE() instead  and it worked for me   but ty for ur answer